# Creating an array of Objects and then setting the member variables

Tags: php, arrays, object, loops

This is the class that I have created in PHP

```
class userinfo
    {
        public $username;
        public $totalscore;
        public $userid;
    }
```

The code below is in a finite loop, and `i` is set to `0` before entering the loop. And the variable `user_array` is defined to be an array using the following code:

```
$user_array = array();

(some code here...)

    $i++;
    $user_array[i] = new userinfo();
    $user_array[i]->totalscore = $stattotal;
    $user_array[i]->userid = $id;
```

For some reason I cant understand why this wont work. I need to create an array of objects. And each object must hold three variables. How do I go about doing so ?

Thank you in Adv. for your Help !

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump` you array?

Comment: It should be `$i` in your object array, `$user_array[$i]`.

Comment: Pro tip: put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of your script, and never ignore any warning shown.

Comment: so is the code correct if I do the modification ? Like is the logic correct ? Also can i assign the object variables the way I have mentioned above ?      $user_array[$i]->totalscore=$stattotal;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked fine for me, remember the `$` when using variables.

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/muv-yx6

Answer (score 1):

You must have a dollar sign (`$i`) before all variables in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **get_class_vars** method to get all properties of class

```
$my_class = new myclass();

$class_vars = get_class_vars(get_class($my_class));

foreach ($class_vars as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name : $value\n";
}
```

SOURCE : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php